# legends orientation in ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

In ggvis how to make legend vertical?

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
layer_points() %>%
add_legend("fill",properties = legend_props( legend = list(x = 500, y = 50)))
```

It puts the legends horizontally. I want it to be vertical.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, size = ~cyl, fill = ~cyl) %>% layer_points() %>% add_legend(c("size", "fill"))
```

### Output chart:

[image]

Hope this helps.

### Edit:

I explored the `add_legend` properties and unfortunately I do not see any way of achieving vertical continues scale legend using `ggvis` for now, however it can be achieved using `ggplot2`.

R code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = cyl))+geom_point()
```

Output chart:

[image]