# How to change legend position in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

I would like to change the default position of the legend in a `ggvis` plot.

```r
library(ggvis)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(x=~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
    layer_points()
```

By default, the legend is on the right side. How to put it on the top?

With `ggplot` you can achieve this simply but I could not find any similar way to do the same with `ggvis`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg, fill=cyl)) +
    geom_point() + 
    theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

---

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396854/legends-orientation-in-ggvis) suggests that up until now you cannot change the orientation of the legend, but is it true for the position as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `?add_legend` and `?legend_props`. I don't think you can do `position=top` etc, but you could use the x and y ranges of the data to position the legend exactly at the mid-top like with `position='top'` in `ggplot()`.

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(x=~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_legend("fill", properties=legend_props(
               legend=list(x=scaled_value("x", 3.25), y=scaled_value("y", 40))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thx. Strange that if I add tooltip as well, the legend disappears...  `. %>% add_tooltip(function(x) x$wt)`

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour with `add_tooltip()`?

Comment: yes, unfortunately am unlikely to figure this one out, perhaps post a new Q? cheers

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452191/how-to-change-legend-position-of-ggvis-when-using-tooltip-as-well/35453498#35453498) is the answer.