# How to change legend position of ggvis when using tooltip as well?

Tags: r, ggvis

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359622/how-to-change-legend-position-in-ggvis) shows how to change the position of the legend in a ggvis object. However, if tooltips are added as well, the legend disappears.

```
library(ggvis)
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_legend(
        "fill", 
        properties = legend_props(
            legend = list(
                x = scaled_value("x", 3.25), 
                y = scaled_value("y", 40)
            )
        )
    ) %>%
    add_tooltip(function(df) df$wt)
```

Any idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/125), you can try adding the below at the end of your code as a workaround:

```
... %>% set_options(duration = 0)
```